# Getting the n-th entry in a structure

Tags: entries, structure

I guess I could always loop through the structure but is there a simple way to directly get the n-th entry in a structure? (at a given level)
Something like:

```
{% set $fifth_listing = craft.entries.section('listing').level('1').pos('5') %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close! This should work:

```
 {% set $fifth_listing = craft.entries.section('listing').level('1').nth(5) %}
```

Comment: Is that an undocumented parameter? It's not listed here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries

Comment: The `craft.entries` tag returns an `ElementCriteriaModel`. The `nth()` function is listed in the `ElementCriteriaModel` docs here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#nth.